# Is the RFID RC522 capable of reading NFC tags?

Tags: arduino, nfc, rfid

I recently purchased the RFID RC522 reader/writer,along with some NFC Mifare classic 1K 13.56mhz tags. The seller on Amazon mentioned that the NFC tags were compatible with the rc522 reader/writer; however, I have not been able scan the tags. I was wondering, is it really possible to scan NFC tags with the RC522 reader/writer?
thanks
[nfc tags](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FR6M8SS)
[RFID RC522 module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01KFM0XNG)

Answer (score 7):

Is it partially true. Depends on the NFC tag you're using, there are 4 different NFC tags types working in different protocol technologies. You can check it in the following [link](http://nfc-forum.org/our-work/specifications-and-application-documents/specifications/tag-type-technical-specifications/).

As I can see in the specs, RC522 supports ISO14443A and all variants of MIFARE products.

If I'm not wrong (long time not working with NFC):

- Type 1: You can't scan those tags
- Type 2: You can scan those tags (based on Mifare Ultralight)
- Type 3: You can't scan those tags
- Type 4: You can scan some, not all, of those tags (partially based on Mifare DESFire)

As Type 2 and Type 4 NFC tags are based on MIFARE tags in general you should be able to scan those type of tags.

Answer (score 5):

The RC522 operates at 13.56 Mhz which is NFC's frequency, and the spec sheet says it natively supports: `mifare1 S50, mifare1 S70 MIFARE Ultralight, mifare Pro, MIFARE DESFire`. It might not work with other tags for whatever reason.

Confirm the NFC tag that you're testing with is working (by using it with your phone) and confirm which kind of tag it is (you can do that with [this app (NFC Easiwayv Tools)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.easitag.easiwayvnfc&hl=en). After that, make sure that you're operating the antenna correctly (as in, its powered on and listening for tags).