# Different NFC ID and RFID UID value

Tags: nfc, uniqueidentifier, rfid, android-things, serial-number

I'm developing software for an Android Things device with RFID reader RC522. I use this library: https://github.com/Galarzaa90/android-things-rc522

My task querying the RC533 RFID reader:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {
    mRc522.stopCrypto();
    while (true) {
        ........
        byte[] uuid = mRc522.getUid();
        return mRc522.selectTag(uuid);
    }
}
```

In my activity I use this to convert the UID value into a string:

```
String tagRC522 = toHexString(mRc522.getUid(), "")
```

Another application in our ecosystem used to scan the NFC tags on an Android smartphone:

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

    String tagNFC = bytesToHex(tagFromIntent.getId());
    ....
}
```

Other apps from Play Store (e.g. *NFC Tools*) give the same results as the code of the smartphone app above.

The problem I face now is that the value `tagRC522` (on the Android Things device using RC522) does not match the value `tagNFC` (in the smartphone app).

```
Tag1  
    tagRC522 = 45DOD86528
    tagNFC   = 45DOD865

Tag2 
    tagRC522 = 3567500103
    tagNFC   = 35675001

Tag3
    tagRC522 = 88046f12F1
    tagNFC   =   046F12CA193A84

Tag4
    tagRC522 = 3EBA46D517
    tagNFC   = 3EBA46D5
```

Why are the results between the two applications different? How must I change my Android Things code? Android mobile is production code and a many data in firebase in tagNFC version, I couldn't change that.

([Image of the tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv79d.jpg))

Comment: Do you have always the same results ?

Comment: Yes, always same results.

Comment: Maybe you face the same problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44814718/is-the-rfid-rc522-capable-of-reading-nfc-tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The results are essentially the same for the RC522 and Android's built-in NFC reader. The main differences are that the library that you use for the RC522

1. includes the checksum  (BCC) in the UID field, and
2. performs anti-collision only for cascade level 1.

This means that only the first 4 bytes of the value obtained through `mRc522.getUid()` are the UID value. The last (5th byte) is the XOR checksum over the previous 4 bytes. This is the BCC byte from the raw anti-collsion frame. If you want to calculate that for the value received through `tagFromIntent.getId()`, you could do something like this:

```
byte[] uid = tagFromIntent.getId();
byte[] uidWithBCC = new byte[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    uidWithBCC[i] = uid[i];
    uidWithBCC[4] ^= uid[i];
}
```

Similarly, in order to turn the value from `mRc522.getUid()` into the value from `tagFromIntent.getId()`, you could just drop the last byte:

```
byte[] uidWithBCC = mRc522.getUid();
byte[] uid = new byte[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    uid[i] = uidWithBCC[i];
}
```

Moreover, for tags with a double or tripple size UID, the value returned by `mRc522.getUid()` is the value raw response of the PICC to casecade level 1 anti-collision. Consequently, it consists of the cascade tag (0x88) followed by the first 3 bytes of the UID, followed by the BCC. Hence, if you want to map the value that you received through `tagFromIntent.getId()` to the value obtained from `mRc522.getUid()`, you need to extract the first 3 bytes of the UID, prepend the cascade tag and append the BCC:

```
    byte[] uid = tagFromIntent.getId();
    if (uid.length > 4) {
        uid[0] = (byte)0x88;
    }
    byte[] trimmedUidWithBCC = new byte[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        trimmedUidWithBCC[i] = uid[i];
        trimmedUidWithBCC[4] ^= uid[i];
    }
```

Unfortunately, this cannot easily be done the other way round. The missing bytes on the Android Things/RC522 side are not something that you could easily calculate from the other bytes. Instead, you would need to modify the library to perform further cascade levels in the anti-collision procedure. Only then you will be able to obtain the complete double and tripple size UIDs.